# Ubuntu - setting 'from' email address for a cron job

Tags: ubuntu, cron, postfix-mta

I am trying to set the from address for crontab.

As I am on google cloud + sendgrid, I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) guideline.

I then added two more steps based on [this](http://semi-legitimate.com/blog/item/how-to-rewrite-outgoing-address-in-postfix) guideline.

Everything works fine if I send the email as in the google docs example:

```
echo 'Test passed.' | mail -s Test-Email EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM
```

But, for some bizarre reason, for cron jobs, I get the 'from' address to be (confirmed in syslog):

```
<userid@hostname@domain>
```

This results in SendGrid assigning the 'to' address as the 'from' with the subject containing the 'from' address:

```
Cron <from@mydomain> 'cron command'
```

What I am not clear is how to create a mapping that would force a cronjob 'from' to look like either:

`userid@domain` or `hostname@domain` (this is what I get when I send the email from the command line).

Answer (score 1):

all I needed to do was to remove the following line from /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

I did set it initially to have a specific hostname as described in [this](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html) postfix guideline but this caused a clash with address rewriting.

Once removed, config in `canonical` and `generic` files works as expected.